# Why both hashCode() and equals() exist

Tags: java

why java Object class has two methods hashcode() and equals()? One of them looks redundant and its percolated to the bottom most derived class?

Comment: You could at least try reading the API -- the Javadoc for Object.hashcode() explicitly says "This method is supported for the benefit of hashtables such as those provided by java.util.Hashtable."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you think one is redundant? They say different things:

- `hashCode` is "give me some way of efficiently seeing whether two objects are *likely* to be equal"
- `equals` is "check whether this object *is genuinely* equal to another"

You definitely need both - [although I don't believe they should really be in Object in the first place](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/12/05/redesigning-system-object-java-lang-object).

You absolutely need hash codes in order to perform efficient lookups with hash tables - and you absolutely need further equality checks because hashes *will* collide (there are far more possible strings than hash codes, for example).

Comment: "I don't believe they should really be in Object." Do you mean both of them, or just hashCode()? equals() as a final method to check identity (probably named differently to avoid confusion) would seem in the right place to me. equals() as a virtual method to check equality does seem to be in the wrong place, though.

Comment: @Martinho: Both. Reference identity can be checked with == already... but most types don't really have the concept of "equality" or a sensible hash based on their data - so why advertise them for all objects? The blog post has more details, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you override equals() you MUST override hashcode() as well.

Failure to do so
will result in a violation of the general contract for Object.hashCode, which will
prevent your class from functioning properly in conjunction with all hash-based
collections, including HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.

Here is the contract, copied from the Object specification [JavaSE6]:

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execu-
  tion  of  an  application,  the  hashCode  method  must  consistently  return  the
  same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the
  object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execu-
  tion of an application to another execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then call-
  ing the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same
  integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects
  must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be
  aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve
  the performance of hash tables.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental idea is that by comparing `hashcode()`s it's quick to check whether two objects are *probably* equal. If their hashcodes are equal, then the objects probably are equal (not necessarily, but it's a good guess). Then a more profound (and more expensive) check with `equals()` is performed. This is important to speed up all kind of look-ups (from maps etc).

Comment: Also, because hashCode is an int, it is be used to speed up look-ups even more by acting as an index into something with random access..

Answer (score 1):

equals is to compare objects, hashcode is used to generate a hash value from an object, which will then be used by the java map containers (Hashtable, Map etc).

it's common practice to override them together (if you override hashcode, you need to override equals and vice versa).

Comment: @Neeraj: hashCode can have collisions, i.e., objects with the same hashCode, aren't always the same.

Comment: There it is not for. Two entirely different objects can have the same hashcode. Imagine, the hashcode has a max value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, while you can in theory create an infinite amount of distinct objects.