# How can I check if two ArrayList differ, I don't care what's changed

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I check if two ArrayLists differ from one another? I don't care what's the difference, I just want to know if they're not the same.

I'm fetching scores list from a database every minute, and only if the scores list that I fetched is different from the one I fetched a minute ago I want to send it to the client.

Now the value of the ArrayList is actually a class that I created (that contains name, lvl, rank, score).

Do I need to implement `equals()` on it?

Comment: What is "same"? Is a list `[1, 2, 3]` the same as `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`? What about `[3, 2, 1]`? Or `["one", "two", "three"]`? If you don't care to define what counts as same/difference, we can just say use `==` and `!=`. At least that's _one_ definition of whether or not two objects are the same.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Unless specified otherwise "are those the same" means `equals()` in Java. In don't see why this should be put in question here.

Comment: @Joachim: if OP means to define equality using `equals`, then OP would already know the answer and wouldn't ask the question in the first place, right? (i.e. Q: How can I check if `list1` is `equals` to `list2`? A: Use `list1.equals(list2)`)

Comment: i require exact same values with same types and same order

Comment: equals() it is, then. Just make sure that your values are of a class which defines an equals-function and you should be fine.

Comment: @Lizzan - there are classes that don't define equals? How can I achieve this?

Comment: @kgrad: that's of course not possible, but there are many classes that define `equals()` based on object identity alone (such as `java.lang.Object`). A colloquial shortcut for that behaviour is "classes that don't implement `equals()`".

Comment: @ufk: I'm still curious what your use case is, because if you need a way to make sure that a list has not been modified at all for e.g. security purposes, then `equals` is not a foolproof way of doing it. The "I don't care what's changed" part is what needs to be clarified, because there can be a lot of changes to a list that would not be detectable by `equals`.

Comment: it's a scores array that i fetch from database. i want to send it to the client only if it was changed from the previous time i fetched the scores from db.

The Values are from a class that I created, do i need to implement equals on it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple method that checks if 2 Array Lists contain the same values regardless their order.

```
 //the name of the method explains it well...
    public boolean isTwoArrayListsWithSameValues(ArrayList<Object> list1, ArrayList<Object> list2)
    {
        //null checking
        if(list1==null && list2==null)
            return true;
        if((list1 == null && list2 != null) || (list1 != null && list2 == null))
            return false;

        if(list1.size()!=list2.size())
            return false;
        for(Object itemList1: list1)
        {
            if(!list2.contains(itemList1))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 81):

#### On the definition of "sameness"

As Joachim noted, for most application, [`List.equals(Object o)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) definition works:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

Depending on how you're using it, though, this may not work as expected. If you have a `List<int[]>`, for example, it doesn't quite work because arrays inherit `equals` from `Object` which defines equality as reference identity.

```
    List<int[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    List<int[]> list2 = Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // prints "false"
```

Also, two lists with different type parameter can be `equals`:

```
    List<Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // prints "true"
```

You also mentioned that the list must contain elements with the same type. Here's yet another example where the elements don't have the same type, and yet they're `equals`:

```
    List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    list2.add(new LinkedList<String>());
    System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // prints "true"
```

So unless you clearly define what equality means to you, the question can have very different answers. For most practical purposes, though, `List.equals` should suffice.

---

#### On implementing `equals`

Information after update suggests that `List.equals` will do the job just fine, *provided* that the elements implement `equals` properly (because `List<E>.equals` invokes `E.equals` on the non-`null`-elements, per the API documentation above).

So in this case, if we have, say, a `List<Player>`, then `Player` must `@Override equals(Object o)` to return `true` if `o instanceof Player` and on the relevant fields, they're all `equals` (for reference types) or `==` (for primitives).

Of course, when you `@Override equals`, you should also `@Override int hashCode()`. The barely acceptable minimum is to `return 42;`; slightly better is to `return name.hashCode();`; best is to use a formula that involves all the fields on which you define `equals`. A good IDE can automatically generate `equals/hashCode` methods for you.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

  - *Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals*
  - *Item 9: Always override hashcode when you override equals*

#### API links

- [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`Object.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
- [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) - not needed here, but another important Java API contract

#### Related questions

On `equals/hashCode` combo:

- [Overriding equals and hashcode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Why both hashCode() and equals() exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469282/why-both-hashcode-and-equals-exist)
- [How to ensure hashCode() is consistent with equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410236/how-to-ensure-hashcode-is-consistent-with-equals)

On `equals` vs `==`:

- [Difference between equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)
- [why equals() method when we have == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)
- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 13):

Use `equals()`. As long as the elements inside the lists implement `equals()` correctly it will return the correct values.

Unless you want to ignore the order of the values, then you should dump the values in two `Set` objects and compare those using `equals()`.

Comment: If you put the values in a set, you remove duplicates... You will not be checking if they are the same, only if they contain the same elements. This may or may not be what OP wants. But in my opinion, if one list contains 3 x's and one contains only 2, they are not the same.

Comment: Well, check the length of the two lists first, then dump them into sets if that's what you want.

Comment: @Lizzan: That won't work either. The lists ["a", "a", "b"] and ["a", "b", "b"] have the same length, would be equal if converted to sets, but are still not equal for any reasonable definition of equality of lists.

Comment: Right, but if the OP wants to check for that, equals() will work just fine, as Joachim said first. On the other hand, that does make my previous comment rather unuseful as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Joachim Sauer mentioned in his answer, equals should work if the lists are equal and their contents implement equals correctly. But, it shouldn't work if the items are not in the same "order" since it doesn't use contains for the check. In this sense, it checks for "strict" equality as mentioned by @jarnbjo

```
        //From android's Arraylist implementation
        Iterator<?> it = that.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            Object eThis = a[i];
            Object eThat = it.next();
            if (eThis == null ? eThat != null : !eThis.equals(eThat)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

However, I wanted somewhat different behaviour, I didn't care about order or anything like that. All I wanted was to be sure the two didn't contain the same items.
My solution,

```
    //first check that both are not null and are of same length. (not shown here)
    //if both match, pull out the big guns as below
    ...
    List<Object> comparedList = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
    comparedList.removeAll(listTwo);
    if(comparedList.size() != 0) //there are differences between the two
```

This is less performant since it loops twice, first in `removeAll` and then in `contains` which is called by `removeAll`.

My list was guaranteed to be short so I didn't mind the hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to string and then compare like

```
list1.toString().equals(list2.toString())
```

Comment: Not good if .toString isn't implemented in all the contained objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check the Arraylist as shown below:

```
public  boolean equalLists(List<String> one, List<String> two){     
if (one == null && two == null){
    return true;
}

if((one == null && two != null) 
  || one != null && two == null
  || one.size() != two.size()){
    return false;
}

//to avoid messing the order of the lists we will use a copy
//as noted in comments by A. R. S.
one = new ArrayList<String>(one); 
two = new ArrayList<String>(two);   

Collections.sort(one);
Collections.sort(two);      
return one.equals(two);
}
```

Thanks to [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501142/java-arraylist-how-can-i-tell-if-two-lists-are-equal-order-not-mattering/13501200#13501200)