# Merging two sorted Arraylists into one sorted Arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, mergesort

My code should merge two already sorted arraylists into one sorted arraylist and if one of the arraylists used is not sorted then it should return null.

```
public class MergeSorted {
public static void merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < b.size(); i++) {
        if (i == a.size() || a.get(i) > a.get(j)) {
            a.add(i, b.get(j++));
        }
    }
}  
}
```

This is what I attempted but can't get the idea of returning null if they are not equal, Im new to java and this is my second week so please be patient with me. I know I should have an if statement checking if they are sorted and an else but what should I include inside the if?

Comment: First, only call that method if you already know both lists are sorted (separate problems to resolve ;)) Second, if you have the appropiated `equals()` and `compare()` you  could order the result list using `Collections.sort()`

Comment: I suppose returning `null` implies that you should be creating new array list to store merged result, not modifying source array list.

Comment: `it should return null` First of all you are not returning anything i.e. void.

Comment: If by "sorted" you mean numerical order, then you could simply create a `TreeSet` and insert the contents of both lists there. Using a `Set` merges the data for you so that duplicates are removed. Or do you want to keep duplicate entries?

Comment: Is that a homework task? I cannot image why someone want to return null in case the list is already sorted.

Comment: @Mick I think this is an exercise in writing the "merge" part of the merge sort algorithm, which works on unsorted data structures.

Answer (score 1):

- Please refer to this link for comparing if the List implementation is equal. Please note that the `ArrayList` implementation of yours contains `List<Integer>` and thus the sorting takes place in the natural order. In case of equal return `true` or else `false`. You can change it as required to return any flag.

[Sort and compare 2 lists if equal - List of String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13501200/2931410)

- There are useful Apache Common library classes available, which can help you in merging the array lists that are sorted : This will give you what you are looking for. org.apache.commons.collections4 package.
  [Apache Common Lib version 4 - collate()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#collate-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-)

eg., `List<Integer> mergedList = CollectionUtils.collate(list1, list2);`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Check if the two lists are sorted, if they are then it will merge the two lists into a single sorted list, whereas if the lists are not sorted return null.

**Code Solution:**

Try the following code:

```
public class MergeSorted {
public static List merge(List<Integer> aList, List<Integer> bList) {

    List mergeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //checking if list 'A' is sorted
    List temp = new ArrayList(aList);
    Collections.sort(temp);
    boolean aSorted = temp.equals(aList);

    //checking if list 'B' is sorted
    temp = new ArrayList(bList);
    Collections.sort(temp);
    boolean bSorted = temp.equals(bList);

    //if both lists are sorted then merge them
    if(true == aSorted && true == bSorted) {
        mergeList.addAll(aList);
        mergeList.addAll(bList);
        Collections.sort(mergeList);
    }

   return mergeList; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, can't i use my code with something added for the check?

Comment: i cant use collections.sort or any of this. Also the output has to be an ArrayList and the inputs ArrayLists not lists.

Comment: @JonathonK you can use ArrayList instead of List it's upto you, however List is a better option. The above code is complete and you use it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way is something like this:

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
        if (!isSorted(a) || !isSorted(b)) {
            return null;
        }

        final List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(a.size() + b.size());
        result.addAll(a);
        result.addAll(b);

        Collections.sort(result);

        return result;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(final List<T> list) {
        T prevItem = null;
        for (T item : list) {

            if (prevItem != null && item.compareTo(prevItem) < 0) {
                return false;
            }

            prevItem = item;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

You can easily replace all these generic Ts with Integer if you only need it for them...