# How compare only items in 2 lists?

Tags: java, android

Android 5.0, Java 1.7

I has 2 lists. I need to compare only content of this lists. The order of the elements does not matter.
Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] , [1,2,3,4,5] -> return true

[1,2,3,4] , [1,2,3,4,5] -> return false

[1,3,5,4,2] , [1,2,3,4,5] -> return true
```

Comment: by writing the code that does that, but we're not a handing out code service.

Comment: You an try converting list to SET and then compare them by Collection comparator

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501142/java-arraylist-how-can-i-tell-if-two-lists-are-equal-order-not-mattering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ArrayList - how can I tell if two lists are equal, order not mattering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501142/java-arraylist-how-can-i-tell-if-two-lists-are-equal-order-not-mattering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method would be to use `containsAll` method:

```
if(listOne.containsAll(listTwo) && listTwo.containsAll(listOne)) {
    System.out.println("They are equal");
}
```

Comment: If size of lists are same then one comparison is in-off to full-fill check.

Comment: That's not necessarily true