# Generic Arraylist Equal Lists Extension

Tags: android, generics, arraylist, kotlin

I'm trying to rewrite this code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13501200/8591160) to generic ArrayList extension in Kotlin.

```
public  boolean equalLists(List<String> one, List<String> two){     
    if (one == null && two == null){
        return true;
    }

    if((one == null && two != null) 
      || one != null && two == null
      || one.size() != two.size()){
        return false;
    }

    //to avoid messing the order of the lists we will use a copy
    //as noted in comments by A. R. S.
    one = new ArrayList<String>(one); 
    two = new ArrayList<String>(two);   

    Collections.sort(one);
    Collections.sort(two);      
    return one.equals(two);
}
```

I came up with the code below but I'm getting `Unresolved reference: T`

```
fun ArrayList<T>.equalLists(one: ArrayList<T>?, two: ArrayList<T>?): Boolean {
    if (one == null && two == null) {
        return true
    }

    if (one == null && two != null || one != null && two == null || one?.size != two?.size) {
        return false
    }

    val oneCopy = ArrayList(one)
    val twoCopy = ArrayList(two)

    oneCopy.sort()
    twoCopy.sort()

    return one == two
}
```

How to properly implement this in Kotlin?

Comment: You need to define Type in signature . Use `fun <T>` in starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you found a workable solution, but I believe a more Kotlin-idiomatic solution would be to define this on the `List` interface itself, rather than `ArrayList` specifically, and can also be declared as an extension on nullable `List` references to be equivalent to the original Java code (which supported two null lists as arguments):

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> List<T>?.containsSameElementsAs(other: List<T>?) = when {
    (this == null) xor (other == null) -> false // if only one is null
    (this?.size != other?.size) -> false // if both null, or have different sizes
    (this?.size == 1) -> this == other // avoid allocations for single element
    else -> this?.sorted() == other?.sorted()
}
```

Might also be worth considering using a `Set` instead if the order is not important and duplicates aren't meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of Generics in kotlin

First created custom pojo class named as Product:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    int id;
    String mName;

    public Product(int id, String mName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return id == product.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Then add below code in onCreate() method:

```
val p1 = Product(1, "abc")
val p2 = Product(2, "abc")
val p3 = Product(3, "abc")
val p4 = Product(4, "abc")
val p5 = Product(5, "abc")

val p11 = Product(1, "abc")
val p22 = Product(12, "sdg")
val p33 = Product(3, "xfg")
val p44 = Product(14, "pqr")
val p55 = Product(5, "fhtryt")

val mProduList1 = ArrayList<Product>()
val mProduList2 = ArrayList<Product>()

mProduList1.add(p1)
mProduList1.add(p2)
mProduList1.add(p3)
mProduList1.add(p4)
mProduList1.add(p5)


mProduList2.add(p11)
mProduList2.add(p22)
mProduList2.add(p33)
mProduList2.add(p44)
mProduList2.add(p55)

equalLists(mProduList1, mProduList2)
```

Then create generic function named as "equalLists":

```
public fun equalLists(one: ArrayList<*>?, two: ArrayList<*>?): Boolean {
    if (one == null && two == null) {
    return true
}

if (one == null && two != null || one != null && two == null || one?.size != two?.size) {
    return false
}

val oneCopy = ArrayList(one)
val twoCopy = ArrayList(two)

sortProduct(oneCopy)
sortProduct(twoCopy)


return one == two

}
```

Then create new function that will cast generic type to product and then sort them:

```
private fun sortProduct(dummyCopy: ArrayList<Any>) {
    (dummyCopy as ArrayList<Product>).sortWith(object: Comparator<Product>{
        override fun compare(p1: Product, p2: Product): Int = when {
            p1.id > p2.id -> 1
            p1.id == p2.id -> 0
            else -> -1
        }
    })

    for(i in dummyCopy){
        Log.e("tagMine", "i.id is " + i.id + " i.mName " + i.mName)
    }
}
```

To define generic function we can choose one of the follwing like use "`<*>`" or can use "`fun<T>`" as below:

1) `public fun equalLists(one: ArrayList<*>?, two: ArrayList<*>?): Boolean {`

2) `fun<T> equalLists(one: ArrayList<T>?, two: ArrayList<T>?): Boolean {`

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with generic ArrayList extension for this.

```
fun <T: Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T>.equalLists(other: ArrayList<T>?): Boolean {
    if (other == null) {
        return true
    }

    if ( size != other.size ) {
        return false
    }

    val thisCopy = ArrayList(this)
    val otherCopy = ArrayList(other)

    thisCopy.sort()
    otherCopy.sort()


    return thisCopy == otherCopy
}
```

Usage:

```
categories.equalLists(otherCategories)
```