# Is there a way to compare strings disregarding the order of objects in a series of commas?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

For example if had a string `"a, b, c, d"`, is it possible to set another string equal to this one if the other string is `"b, c, d, a"`?

Comment: You can sort string characters of both and check equal

Comment: @Eklavya: +1: you're correct., But there could be problems with commas and spaces if the OP isn't careful.

Comment: @paulsm4  Yes you are right, then the better way is splitting by comma removing space and [compare two list equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501142/java-arraylist-how-can-i-tell-if-two-lists-are-equal-order-not-mattering?rq=1)

Comment: @Eklavya: you mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62845623/421195) :)?

Comment: @paulsm4 Not exactly same, compare list not set. See the linked question's answer in my previous comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have to worry about duplicates, you could convert both CSV strings into sets, and then compare:

```
String input1 = "a, b, c, d";
String input2 = "b, c, d, a";
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(input1.split(",\\s*")));
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(input2.split(",\\s*")));

if (set1.equals(set2)) {
    System.out.println("EQUAL");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string "a, b, c, d" is completely different from the string "b, c, d, a".  They cannot ever be evaluated as "equal".

You *CAN*, however, parse the string.  And save the elements "a", "b", "c" and "d" into a [Collection](https://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java), such as a List or a Set.  [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) could be a good choice.

Optionally, you can also write a [Comparitor](https://www.concretepage.com/java/java-8/java-comparator-sortedset) for your collection.

The point is that you cannot evaluate the strings as-is.  You must first choose an appropriate data structure for the string's contents.  Only then can you evaluate  and compare the *values* parsed from the string.