# Why two List<Object[]> not equal in Java?

Tags: java, equals

I have class `Point` with overridden methods `equals()` и `hashCode()`:

```java
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point() {
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Point point = (Point) obj;
        if (this.x != point.getX()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.y != point.getY()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (31 * x + y);
    }
}
```

I create `points`:

```java
        p1 = new Point(1.0, 1.0);
        p2 = new Point(1.0, 2.0);
        p3 = new Point(1.0, 4.0);
        p4 = new Point(5.0, 5.0);
```

This is arrays of Points - combinations:

```java
        Point[] combinationPoints1 = {p1, p2, p3};
        Point[] combinationPoints2 = {p1, p2, p4};
        Point[] combinationPoints3 = {p1, p3, p4};
        Point[] combinationPoints4 = {p2, p3, p4};
```

Create `List<Point[]>`:

```java
List<Point[]> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);

List<Point[]> expectedResult2 = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);
```

Compare 2 `List<Point[]>` and get message `true`:

```java
List<Point[]> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);

List<Point[]> expectedResult2 = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);

expectedResult.equals(expectedResult2);    // TRUE
```

When I'm try change order to this:

```java
List<Point[]> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);

List<Point[]> expectedResult2 = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints2, combinationPoints1, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);
```

When comparing, I get `false`:

```java
expectedResult.equals(expectedResult2);    // FALSE
```

Why?

**UPDATE 29.08.2020**
I have 2 `List<Point[]>`:

```java
// FIRST
List<Point[]> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);
```

and

```java
List<Point[]> actualResult = calculatePoint.getCombinationsElementsOver(startingPoints, pointsOnLine);
```

with contents:

```java
for(Point[] p1 : expectedResult) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p1));
        }
// FIRST

[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (1.0; 4.0)]
[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 4.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
[Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (1.0; 4.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
```

```java
for(Point[] p1 : actualResult) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p1));
        }

// SECOND
[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (1.0; 4.0)]
[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
[Point (1.0; 1.0), Point (1.0; 4.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
[Point (1.0; 2.0), Point (1.0; 4.0), Point (5.0; 5.0)]
```

Through method I check identity lists:

```java
private <T> boolean listEqualsIgnoreOrder(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        return new HashSet<>(list1).equals(new HashSet<>(list2));
    }
```

Why I get `false` when:

```java
boolean result = listEqualsIgnoreOrder(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

Comment: Because of the contract of `List.equals`, as stated in its docs: they're not equal by that definition.

Comment: [Java ArrayList - how can I tell if two lists are equal, order not mattering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13501142)

Comment: Because arrays aren't equal to each other.  You'd have better luck with a `List<List<Point>>`.

Comment: The real point here is that equals for arrays doesn't work as you assume it would. If you would be using list of list of point things would be different. And note: mixing concepts is never a good approach. Either use arrays or lists, but lists of arrays is just weird.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I'll check it out now and get answer

Comment: You have no (good) reason to use `Point[]`. You're better off using `List<Point>`. So `List<Point[]>` would be `List<List<Point>>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, arrays are equal (see the update in the topic)

Comment: @n199a, no, they aren't.  They have equal contents, but that doesn't make the _arrays_ `.equals` to each other. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777257/869736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lists have the same elements but in a different order:

```
List<Point[]> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints1, combinationPoints2, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);

List<Point[]> expectedResult2 = Arrays.asList(combinationPoints2, combinationPoints1, combinationPoints3, combinationPoints4);
```

The `List.equals` method considers two lists to be equal if they contain the "same"  elements in the same order. These two lists do have the same elements, but they are not in the same order. So the `equals` method must return `false`.

There's also a potential issue that stems from the fact that arrays don't implement equals method based on the contents: two different arrays instances with the same contents are not considered "equal" by the equals method. That doesn't come to into play here though: all of your arrays have different contents anyway.