# UnitTest shows the test is failed while expected result and actual result are the same

Tags: java, junit

I am learning JUnit and I am testing a simple method, I have a method which populate a list and return it. Although in unit test I provided the same list, the unit test failed.

**Code**

```
public List<Transaction> retrieveData() throws ParseException {
        List<Transaction> expResult = new ArrayList();
        Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-04-29T13:15:54");
        Transaction tran = new Transaction("A", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
        expResult.add(tran);
        tran = new Transaction("B", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
        expResult.add(tran);
        tran = new Transaction("A", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
        expResult.add(tran);
        tran = new Transaction("B", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
        expResult.add(tran);
        return expResult;

    }
```

**JUnit**

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveData() throws ParseException {
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    List<Transaction> expResult = new ArrayList();
    Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-04-29T13:15:54");
    Transaction tran = new Transaction("A", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    expResult.add(tran);
    tran = new Transaction("B", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    expResult.add(tran);
    tran = new Transaction("A", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    expResult.add(tran);
    tran = new Transaction("B", convertedDate,new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    expResult.add(tran);

    List<Transaction> result = instance.retrieveData();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
```

The failed message and stacktrace are as following

**Error**

```
expected: java.util.ArrayList<[
   Transaction{cardNumber=A, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=B, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=A, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=B, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}]> 
   but was: java.util.ArrayList<[
   Transaction{cardNumber=A, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=B, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=A, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}, 
   Transaction{cardNumber=B, timestamp=Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 EST 2014, price=20.00}]>
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
```

Comment: Have you defined `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Transaction` class?

Comment: no should I override the equals class? would you give me an example

Comment: If you're using eclipse right click on your class, select Source and then "Generate hashCode() and equals()" which will give you a naive implementation. Otherwise I can't give you an example without knowing how you would determine whether two transactions were equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing the lists, your test is asserting the lists are equals, which will call `equals()` on all of the elements within the list.

The default implementation of `equals` for all classes simply asserts that the objects are literally the same (Same pointer).

If you override `equals()` in your `Transaction` class to check the values the class holds instead of the references, the test will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a discussion and thorough answer about a similar issue:

[How can I check if two ArrayList differ, I don't care what's changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989987/how-can-i-check-if-two-arraylist-differ-i-dont-care-whats-changed)

Comment: If your link is to an identical question, flag this one as a duplicate. If it's not an answer to this question, post it as a comment, not an answer.