# Why are two empty ArrayLists with different generic types equal?

Tags: java, generics, equals

I have a doubt regarding how `equals()` method works for `ArrayList`. The below code snippet prints `true`.

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> s1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(s1.equals(s));
```

Why does it print `true`?

Comment: because both are empty..., take a look into the equals method of the `ArrayList`

Comment: Note: `s == s1` will return false

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2990174/5193194) answer it explains it all

Comment: Another note: The generic types *lost* at runtime due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: @LanceJava for (==) there is Incompatible operand types ArrayList<String> and ArrayList<Integer>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look the [doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for the [equals()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `ArrayList`

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

Since there are no elements, all the conditions satisfied and hence `true`.

If you add elements to the both list (*atleast one in each*), to see the desired output.

Comment: If the lists both had an element, set to null - how would the comparison then be? By value alone or type as well?

Comment: @JeppeRask `null` is equals to `null` :)

Comment: links don't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

The contract of the [`List.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is that two lists are equal if all their elements are equal (in terms of `equals()`). Here, both are empty lists, so they are equal. The generic type is irrelevant, as there are anyway no list elements to compare.

However, they are not equal in terms of `==` as these are two different objects.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for details between `equals()` and `==`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ArrayList implementation of the equals method from the AbstractList
with a few commments what it actually does:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o == this) // Not the same list so no return
       return true;
   if (!(o instanceof List)) // is an instance of List, so no return 
       return false;

   ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
   ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
   while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) { // Both have no next, so no loop    here
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
   }
   return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext()); // Both validate to false, so negating false return true in the end.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers pointed, equals returns true because both objects are instances of `List` and have the same size (0).

It's also worth mentioning that the fact that one `List` contains `Integer` and the other `String` does not affect the behaviour because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java.