# I was told to emulate an ArrayDeque with a equals(Object obj) method

Tags: java, generics, equals, deque

So I have to do as a homework in my class, to implement my own version of a Deque supported on an array, which can be accessed by both the tail or the head. My teacher provided us a JUnit test class to check if all our methods work. Two of those are clone() and equals(), I need this last one for the test class to check if two cloned ArrayDeque are the same.
I just need help with this because it won't work with the next code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    for (Object elem : items)
    {
        E x = (E) elem;
        if (!x.equals((E)obj)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It would really help me if someone could give me a hand with this...

Thank you very much

EDIT: `items` is an attribute with the array of elements of the deque
EDIT2:

Is this okay then?

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    TSBDeQueue object = (TSBDeQueue) obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if (!object.items[i].equals(this.items[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast to call `equals()`.

Comment: If `obj` is another `ArrayDeque`, what do you think `x.equals(obj)` will return?

Comment: @shmosel this is what I don't understand, specially what I'm suposed to get as a param

Comment: You need to iterate over `this` and `obj` in parallel, and return when you find a mismatch.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989987/how-can-i-check-if-two-arraylist-differ-i-dont-care-whats-changed

Comment: Won't let me because obj is only one attribute, it has no [ ] at all so the compiler won't let me iterate over it.

Comment: I don't know what that means. You're already iterating over `this` with your `for` loop. If `items` is an array, just loop over both with an index instead.

Comment: You need to cast `obj` to your `ArrayDeque` and then you can iterate over it's elements.

Comment: What about now @shmosel ?

Comment: Better. But you've overlooked the possibility of `object.items` being shorter than `this.items`.

Comment: @shmosel Test Class launches NullPointerException: http://prntscr.com/gyc0xy

Comment: You're not checking if `obj` is null (or if `items` is null, assuming that's possible).

Comment: You're also casting without verifying that `obj` is, in fact, a `TSBDeQueue`.

Comment: I don't know how to verify that it is a TSBDeQueue. Anyways, what does it have to do with a NullPointerException? I'm not sure if that may be the reason of that error

Comment: `a.equals(b)` throws a `NullPointerException` if `a` is null. Use `Objects.equals(a, b)` instead (or `(a == null) ? (b == null) : a.equals(b)`). Also, `object.items[i].equals(this.items[i])` throws an NPE if `object` is null; you can't work around that, other than by testing `object == null` explicitly.

Comment: Or, rather than using the loop explicitly, you can use `Arrays.equals(object.items[i], this.items[i])`.