# Data transformation

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have data composed of a list of `employers` and a list of `workers`.  Each has a many-to-many relationship with the other (so an employer can have many workers, and a worker can have many employers).

The way the data is retrieved (and given to me) is as follows: each `employer` has an array of `workers`.  In other words:

```
employer n has:
  worker x, worker y etc.
```

So I have a bunch of employer objects each containing an array of workers.

I need to transform this data (and basically invert the relationship).  I need to have a bunch of `worker` objects, each containing an array of `employers`.  In other words:

```
worker x has:
  employer n1, employer n2 etc.
```

The context is hypothetical so please don't comment on why I need this or why I am doing it this way.  I would really just like help on the algorithm to perform this transformation (there isn't *that* much data so I would prefer readability over complex optimizations which reduce complexity).  (Oh and I am using Java, but pseudocode would be fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a [`Map<Worker,Set<Employer>>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for this, or possibily a [`Multimap<Worker,Employer>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava.

In pseudocode:

```
initialize employerMap(worker => set of employers)
for every employer n do
    for every worker x in n.workers do
         employerMap[x].add(n)
```

Essentially a `Worker` can be mapped to multiple `Employer`, so you either:

- Have a `Map<Worker,Set<Employer>>`

  - each key in a `Map` can only have one value, so the value in this case is a `Set` of values
- Have a `Multimap<Worker,Employer>`

  - `Multimap` can map a key to multiple values

---

#### Example

Here's an example of doing the mapping. Note that storing the data in `Object[][] arr` like this is definitely not recommended, and is only used as part of the example. Concentrate on the actual mapping part.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MultiMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[][] arr = {
            { "IBM",    new String[] { "Joe", "Jack", "Carol"   }},
            { "MS",     new String[] { "Jack", "Andy", "Carol" }},
            { "Google", new String[] { "Bob", "Alice", "Carol"  }},
        };
        Map<String,Set<String>> employerMap =
            new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();

        for (Object[] data : arr) {
            String employer = (String) data[0];
            String[] workers = (String[]) data[1];
            for (String worker : workers) {
                Set<String> employers = employerMap.get(worker);
                if (employers == null) {
                    employerMap.put(worker, employers = new HashSet<String>());
                }
                employers.add(employer);
            }
        }

        for (String worker : employerMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(worker + " works for " + employerMap.get(worker));
        }
    }
}
```

This prints (order may vary):

```
Alice works for [Google]
Jack works for [IBM, MS]
Bob works for [Google]
Andy works for [MS]
Carol works for [IBM, Google, MS]
Joe works for [IBM]
```

I recommend keeping the data in a `Map` like this, but if you must transform the list of employees to an array for some reason, you can use [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

You should generally prefer `List` and other Java Collections Framework classes to arrays, though.

---

#### On implementing `equals`, `hashCode`, etc

The above example uses `String` for simplicity. You probably should have an actual `Worker` and `Employer` types instead, which is a good thing. You have to make sure that they implement `equals` and `hashCode` properly, though.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition*

  - *Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals*
  - *Item 9: Always override hashcode when you override equals*

#### API links

- [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`Object.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
- [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) - not needed here, but another important Java API contract

#### Related questions

On `equals/hashCode` combo:

- [Overriding equals and hashcode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Why both hashCode() and equals() exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469282/why-both-hashcode-and-equals-exist)
- [How to ensure hashCode() is consistent with equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410236/how-to-ensure-hashcode-is-consistent-with-equals)

On `equals` vs `==`:

- [Difference between equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)
- [why equals() method when we have == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)
- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 3):

Not java-specific, but here's the approach:

- make a dictionary of `<Worker, Set<Employer>>`,
- iterate through all the workers of each employer, and
- for every worker, add the current employer to the `Dict[Worker]` set

You'll need to add a check to create the set the first time each worker is found.

Comment: I understand bullet 1, but how to I do bullet 2 given the dictionary made in the bullet 1?

Comment: Make a function that takes your list of employer objects, creates the dictionary, and walks the employer list, adding each worker to the dictionary.

Comment: sorry if this is obnoxious, but could I please have pseudocode, I can't seem to wrap my head around it?